# I'm trying to create a Chi-Squared Feature Selection however there is an error in load the dataset

Tags: python, dataset, data-science, feature-selection, chi-squared

I'm trying to create a Chi-Squared Feature Selection however there is an error in load the dataset. I load the dataset using Panda library. I'm trying to use the train_test_split() function form scikit-learn and use 67% of the data for training and 33% for testing. The dataset used has the header on row 1. How to solve this problem?

This are the coding used.

```
# example of chi squared feature selection for categorical data
from pandas import read_csv
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from matplotlib import pyplot
 
# load the dataset
def load_dataset():
    # load the dataset as a pandas DataFrame
    data = read_csv('GDS-and-MMSE-balanced', header=None)
    # retrieve numpy array
    dataset = data.values
    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = dataset[:, :-1]
    y = dataset[:,-1]
    # format all fields as string
    X = X.astype(str)
    return X, y
 
# prepare input data
def prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test):
    oe = OrdinalEncoder()
    oe.fit(X_train)
    X_train_enc = oe.transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = oe.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_enc, X_test_enc
 
# prepare target
def prepare_targets(y_train, y_test):
    le = LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(y_train)
    y_train_enc = le.transform(y_train)
    y_test_enc = le.transform(y_test)
    return y_train_enc, y_test_enc
 
# feature selection
def select_features(X_train, y_train, X_test):
    fs = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k='all')
    fs.fit(X_train, y_train)
    X_train_fs = fs.transform(X_train)
    X_test_fs = fs.transform(X_test)
    return X_train_fs, X_test_fs, fs
 
# load the dataset
X, y = load_dataset('GDS-and-MMSE-balanced.csv')
# split into train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)
# prepare input data
X_train_enc, X_test_enc = prepare_inputs(X_train, X_test)
# prepare output data
y_train_enc, y_test_enc = prepare_targets(y_train, y_test)
# feature selection
X_train_fs, X_test_fs, fs = select_features(X_train_enc, y_train_enc, X_test_enc)
# what are scores for the features
for i in range(len(fs.scores_)):
    print('Feature %d: %f' % (i, fs.scores_[i]))
# plot the scores
pyplot.bar([i for i in range(len(fs.scores_))], fs.scores_)
pyplot.show()
```

Below is the error after it was execute

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-669e661525aa> in <module>()
     46 
     47 # load the dataset
---> 48 X, y = load_dataset('GDS-and-MMSE-balanced.csv')
     49 # split into train and test sets
     50 X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=1)

TypeError: load_dataset() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `def load_dataset()` such as:

```
def load_dataset(filepath):
    # load the dataset as a pandas DataFrame
    data = pd.read_csv(filepath, header=None)
    # retrieve numpy array
    dataset = data.values
    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    X = dataset[:, :-1]
    y = dataset[:,-1]
    # format all fields as string
    X = X.astype(str)
    return X, y
```

then, load your datasets, as following:

```
# load the dataset
filepath = 'GDS-and-MMSE-balanced.csv'
X, y = load_dataset(filepath)
```